# Xamarin Watch - Consume web service (Android)

Tags: android, xamarin, tizen-wearable-sdk, android-wear-2.0

I'm trying to call a website from my android watch but the thread exits (The thread 0x5 has exited with code 0 (0x0)) without a result.
I added the permissions "Internet" and "Network_state", which does not change the result. Below my code (done in Tizen and pure Xamarin):

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        textView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.text);
        Button mybtn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnCal);
        SetAmbientEnabled();

        try
        {
            mybtn.Click += delegate
            {
                Task<string> callTask = calculateRoute();
                callTask.Wait();
                string astr = callTask.Result;
            };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string tt = ex.ToString();
        }
    }

    private async Task<string> calculateRoute()
    {
        HttpClient client;
        try
        {
            String RestUrl = "https://www.google.com";
            var uri = new Uri(string.Format(RestUrl, string.Empty));

            client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();

            var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return content;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string tt = ex.ToString();
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Do you have any idea?

Thanks, Jeppen

Comment: I have not used a Tizen wearable, *but* replace your Task Wait/Result w/ `async` to prevent a deadlock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After quite some research I found the solution thanks to: https://github.com/Samsung/Tizen-CSharp-Samples/tree/master/Wearable

Give the app the following permissions:

> ```
> <privilege>http://tizen.org/privilege/internet</privilege>
> <privilege>http://tizen.org/privilege/network.get</privilege>
> <privilege>http://tizen.org/privilege/download</privilege>
> ```

C# code

> ```
> HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.google.lu");
>
>                //get the data
>                 request.Method = "GET";
>                 HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
>
>                 string tt = ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription + "\n";
>                 // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
>                 Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
>                 // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
>                 StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
>                 // Read the content.
>                 string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
> ```

Happy coding, Jeppen

Comment: If you are interesting in Tizen .NET + Xamarin Forms, You can get useful information from https://samsung.github.io/Tizen.NET/